# Palindromic substrings

Tags: python, string, algorithm, palindrome

Given two strings **A** and **B** , each consisting of lower case alphabets, 
is it possible to choose some non empty strings s1 and s2 where s1 is a substring of A, s2 is a substring of B such that s1 + s2 is a palindromic string. Here '+' denotes the concatenation between the strings.

**For example:**

```
Case 1:

A='abc'
B='abc'
```

Solution One possible way of choosing s1 & s2 is s1 = "ab", s2 = "a" such that s1 + s2 i.e "aba" is a palindrome.

```
Case 2:
A='a'
B='b'
```

Solution:There is no possible way to choose s1 & s2 such that s1 + s2 is a palindrome.

Note:
If it is possible , print 'Yes' else print 'No'
What would be the algorithm to finding the palindromic substring between two strings ?

Comment: and a link to a problem and people would not think you are trying to cheat in a programming contest

Answer (score 2):

It is necessary (and sufficient) for the two strings to have one letter in common.

```
def test(a, b):
    return not set(a).isdisjoint(set(b))
```

Comment: The latter `set()` is not even needed, can use a bare string there.

Answer (score 0):

This program gives fairly good results for the problem you have posted.

```
#palindromic substrings in Python
s1='potter'
s2='topper'
count=0
print('substring  substring    allowed \n of s1 \t   of s2\tpalindromes')
for m in range(len(s1)):
   for n in range(m+1,len(s1)+1):   # n > m
    subs1=s1[m:n]               # substring of s1
    l = n-m                     # length of subs1
    print (subs1,'.................................')
    for r in range(len(s2)-l+1):
        subs2=s2[r:r+l]
        print('\t',subs2)
        if subs1==subs2[::-1]:  # string reversal
            print ('\t\t\t',subs1+subs2)
            count=count+1
if count==0:
    print ('No')
else:
    print('Yes')
```

What I have basically done here is taking substrings of s1. The lengths of the substrings are increased gradually like 'p', 'po', 'pot', 'pott', 'potte', 'potter'. And corresponding to each substring of s1, we check substrings of equal length from the other string s2.  A part of the output is shown below:

```
substring  substring    allowed 
 of s1      of s2      palindromes
p .................................
            t
            o
            p
                         pp
            p
                         pp
            e
            r
po .................................
           to
           op
                        poop
           pp
           pe
           er
pot .................................
           top
                        pottop
           opp
           ppe
           per
 :          :              :
 :          :              :
```

As for example, corresponding to 'pot' in s1 we get 'top', 'opp', 'ppe', 'per' in s2 which are of same length as 'pot'. But only 'top' when reversed gives back 'pot'. So when 'pot' is concatenated with 'top' it forms a palindrome. Similarly other palindromes that can be obtained from these two words are 'pp', 'poop', 'pottop', 'oo', 'otto', 'tt', 'ee' and 'rr'.
  But my program does not address the problem of making palindromes of odd number of letters.

Answer (score 0):

There are one thing you need to take in mind : from a string : words pairs are also have single character words;

Explaination :

1. Calculate The number of words calculating function : By Two looping statement
2. Function for Palindrome Checking

Now Login goes like

```
public static int getCountOfPalindromAvailable (String orignalValue){
  int count=0;
  for (int parent=0; parent< orignalValue.length(); parent++ ){
     for (int child=parent; child <orignalValue.length(); child++){ 
          System.out.println(orignalValue.substring(parent, child+1) +" 
      orignalValue");
          if (isPalindrom(orignalValue.substring(parent, child+1))){
             System.out.println(orignalValue.substring(parent, child+1)+" 
           isPalindrom");
             count+=1;
           }
      }
  }
  return count;
}

public static boolean isPalindrom (String orignalValue){
   return orignalValue.equals(new StringBuilder(orignalValue).reverse().toString());
}
```